# Why use the -s file test on a directory?

Tags: perl

I'm reading *Mark Jason Dominus'* [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com). In his directory-walker program he has a subroutine called `dir_size` (at the top of page 22).

In that subroutine he has a statement:

```
my $total = -s $dir;
```

where he already knows that `$dir` is the name of a directory.

`$total` is apparently always set to zero, regardless of the actual size of the directory (which doesn't contradict anything the documentation says).

Is there any reason he doesn't simply say `$total = 0` and avoid the overhead of a system call?

#### Edit

Perhaps it is a distinction between Windows and Unix, since people say that it does not return 0 on Unix systems. I'm using Windows.

But, if he was using Unix and expected it to return the actual size of the directory, why would he then go on to add up all the file sizes himself?

What is it that Unix returns, if not the full size of the directory, just the size of the directory's file map?

#### Edit

I can't find in the Perl documentation any mention of `-s` being used for a directory, much less a description of its return value. It appears to be defined only for use on files.

Comment: Why do you think `$total` is always set to `0`? `-s` returns the size even for directories (in general, I suppose it might not on some OS', but it does for Unix-derivatives.)

Comment: for me, the `perl -E 'say -s q{/etc}'` prints: `3094`, and the `perl -E 'mkdir q{empty}; say -s q{empty}'` prints `68` - the empty directory isn't `0` because contains entries for the `.` and `..`. At least on UNIX-like systems.

Comment: What version of Perl? It appears to be 0 in Cygwin. `$ cat test/junk`
`asdfasdfsdafsdfa`
`$ perl -E 'say -s "./test"'`
`0`

Comment: @blm Not for cygwin, which handles dirs differently, probably because they're really opaque Windows folders. (Size always reports as 0.)

Comment: Re. your edit: see [What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55/94637)

Comment: Re. your second edit: on \*nix, [directories *are* files](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html). I think the file test operators are implemented in terms of `stat`, and not everything `stat` returns is meaningful/accurate on every filesystem. See [`perldoc perlport`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#stat) (although there's no mention of directory size on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

The `-s` filetest operator just returns the `st_size` field from a call to `stat` on its argument.  Exactly what that returns for a directory is up to the OS.

On Unix, `-s` will return the size of the directory.  This is *not* the total size of the files it contains.  Rather, it's the size of the directory entries it contains (not the files they point to, but the entries themselves).  That's why the directory walker still adds up the sizes of the files inside the directory.

Answer (score -1):

So the consensus appears to be that in Windows -s directory returns 0, whereas in Unix it returns the size of the pointer array of the directory.